# How to ignore escape characters in bash script?

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, csv

I am making a bash script and I need a SQL query, but It has escape characters of bash.

I want to read the SQL query without escape characters of bash, why this escape characters are of MySQL.

```
QUERY="SELECT department_id, description FROM departments INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/departaments.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', ' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need to escape the escape the escape characters (so double them).

Comment: I need the string exactly as it is. When I escape a character into this string, MySQL can't to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
read -r -d '' query <<'EOF'
SELECT department_id, description FROM departments INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/departaments.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', ' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
EOF

printf "%s\n" "$query"
```

output

```
SELECT department_id, description FROM departments INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/departaments.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', ' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**edit**, in a case that you need expand variables, remove the `'` from the `EOF`, e.g. like:

```
outfile=/tmp/file
read -r -d '' query <<EOF
SELECT department_id, description FROM departments
INTO OUTFILE '$outfile'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', ' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
EOF
printf "%s\n" "$query"
```

(note the `$outfile` variable) prints

```
SELECT department_id, description FROM departments
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', ' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks!! It's exactly what I needed

Comment: Thanks, I understand!